# How do I turn CSS into example HTML? Is there a shortcut to understanding affects of CSS on nested HTML tags?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've been struggling to simply alter the default NavBar in Bootstrap3 so that even if a menu item isn't selected it will still show up with white text (instead of grayed out text).

I obviously have a limited understanding of CSS selectors. I don't understand the > and/or when the following selector would be applied to my HTML.

Can you turn this into an HTML sample using divs and an a tag to show me what the hierarchy of the HTML tags would be?

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {color:white}

<div class="navbar-default">
      <div class="navbar-nav active"> 
          <a href="test.com">asdfasdfasdf</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Is my guess, right or is it something else?

Here's the real example of the hierarchy which I am attempting to alter so that the text will simply show up as white.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li ><a href="main">Main</a></li>
       <li ><a href="about">About</a></li>
       <li ><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

How can I get the a text to be white:
I've tried these unsuccessfully:

```
.nav > .navbar-nav li a {color:white;}
.nav .navbar-nav > li > a{color:white;}
```

I appreciate any extra help you can give in explaining the css hierarchy shown using simple natural language.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Comment: Try this one `.navbar-brand, .navbar-nav > li > a`

Comment: @NenadVracar trying now...

Comment: You can learn about all CSS selectors and their behaviour at https://css-tricks.com/almanac/ it's really a must read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a
```

means

> Select any `a` element
>   that is a child (`>`) of an element with the "active" class
>   that is a child (`>`) of an element with the "navbar-nav" class
>   that is a descendant (space) of an element with the "navbar-default" class.

which does not match the given HTML because "navbar-nav" and "active" appear on the same element. The correct selector for that HTML is

```
.navbar-default > .navbar-nav.active > a
```

The selector you need to use to style your `a` elements in your real hierarchy is

```
.nav.navbar-nav > li > a
```

as the "nav" and "navbar-nav" classes similarly appear on the same `ul` element rather than on one element nested inside another.

There are tools available that can take certain CSS selectors and generate the corresponding HTML, such as [Emmet](http://emmet.io), a plugin available for a number of IDEs. Due to the nature of selectors however only certain selectors are supported, but the most basic hierarchical combinators such as `>` and `+` are supported which will cover the vast majority of use cases.

Comment: This is fantastic explanation and you got the answer exactly. I pasted it in and it works.  Now I will read your explanation even more closely.  Thanks so much for the great, fast, and really nice answer.

Comment: Is class concatenation required here? For specificity purposes?

Comment: @hungerstar It is done for specificity purposes.  Thanks for your great question.

Comment: @hungerstar: I cannot answer that - only the OP can. It depends entirely on their needs. I'm just following their examples as closely as possible without making too many assumptions about their markup or their CSS.

Comment: @BoltClock The info on Emmet is a great addition.  I will check it out.  Again, thanks for the great answer and explanation. I'm marking as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would no directly change the Bootstrap CSS file.

Make your own CSS file. Place the link below the Bootstrap one in the HTML.

That way anything you write in your CSS will override the Bootstrap CSS.

A good way to find out what exactly you need to change is using Dev Tools in chrome. Right click on your page and select *Inspect*. You can traverse through the DOM and find exactly what CSS you need to change.

Answer (score -1):

More easily way to do this without any complication is adding a class for a element and reference from css by class

```
<a class="mylnk">Main</a>
```

in CSS add

```
.mylnk {color:white !important}
```

Comment: I tried that exact thing.  Trying the direct route and just so we all know.  It does not work properly.  It drove me crazy.  Bootstrap overrides (or cascades) that away I guess.

Comment: @daylight That only works if there isn't a selector with higher specificity already applying the property.

Comment: Add !important to the rule to override the bootstrap rules, I have fixed my answer to include !important in the rule

Comment: @xzegga That !important inclusion is interesting and I appreciate you adding it to the answer.  I will tryit out as a learning thing.  Thanks very much. It may be very useful in the near future.  ** EDIT - FYI : I tried this just now and it still didn't show up as white text.  I can see the class is set properly when I view it in Chrome tools after rendering.  The answer by Boltclock does work though.  Thanks again for all your input.

Comment: Yes, I have added important to my answer,  If you want to learn more about !important declaration read this https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: Can you add a print screen of your selector in google inpector?, I would like to see what is overriding the class, or if you have a public link would be very usefull

Comment: @daylight please avoid using `!important` at this time as you are new to CSS. Only when you have a solid grasp of CSS should you begin to use `!important`. It increases the specificity of your selector by a huge amount and will make it cumbersome to override it later if need be. There is a place for `!important` but often subtle increases in a selector's specificity is the way to go.

Comment: @hungerstar I have more than 15 years working with html/css, and in some case, when you work with frameworks that use important too, is the only way to override the rules written not for you for general purposes, is for this reazon that would be very usefull to view the google inspector, to give a better solution instead important declaration.